# Why property is not referenced when binded value changes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I realized that Property get/set is not referenced when value changes in DataGridView (DataTable is binded to DataGridView)

My Code is like this

```
    private DataTable _dt;
    public DataTable Dt
    {
        get
        {
            return _dt;
        }
        set
        {
            _dt = value;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        Dt.Rows.Add(19, "kim");
        Dt.Rows.Add(25, "Lee");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
    }
```

As i unsderstand, binding means that if UI control value changes, original value also changes.
So I expected that DataTable's Set Property is referenced when i change value on DataGridView. but didn't.

Please someone explain why is so.

Comment: Not really, you need to implement in the classes that would change, the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Changing a cell in the grid will not set the entire datatable back to a new value, but the values _inside_ the datatable probably do change.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is true of MVVM when you are using WPF usually, but is common in WinForms too. You are setting the data source for a whole datagrid though. When you change a value inside the grid this will not trigger set Dt to be called. If you want to be notified when a cell value changes you would need to use one of the events of the grid.